# In dart how can I get a map of fields from a template and a string?

Tags: dart

```
var template = '/test/:key1/tester/:key2';
var filledIn = '/test/12/tester/3';
```

How can I get an map like this given inputs above?

```
[
  key1: 12,
  key2: 3
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better solution that gives the exact format you asked for.

```
void main() {
  final template = Template('/test/:key1/tester/:key2');
  print(template.parse('/test/12/tester/3')); // {key1: 12, key2: 3}
}

class Template {
  Template(this.source);
  final String source;
  List<String> _parts;
  Iterable<int> _params;

  List<String> get parts => _parts ??= source.split('/');
  Iterable<int> get params => _params ??= parts
      .where((part) => part.startsWith(':'))
      .map((param) => parts.indexOf(param));

  Map<String, String> parse(String string) {
    final p = string.split('/');
    return Map.fromEntries(
        params.map((index) => MapEntry(parts[index].substring(1), p[index])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works but it may not be the most elegant solution.

`Map.from()` is used because `List.asMap()` uses an Unmodifiable list.

```
final template = '/test/:key1/tester/:key2';
final filledIn = '/test/12/tester/3';

final params = Map.from(template.split('/').asMap())
  ..removeWhere((i, part) => !part.startsWith(':'));
final values = Map.from(filledIn.split('/').asMap())
  ..removeWhere((i, part) => !params.containsKey(i));

print(params.values); // [:key1, :key2]
print(values.values); // [12, 3]
```